# condition for position vector for another origin

Tags: vectors

Let $r_1, r_2 ,\ldots,r_n$  be the position vector of points $P_1 , P_2 ,\ldots, P_n$ relative to origin O . If a vector equation holds that is $a_1 r_1 + a_2 r_2 +\cdots +a_n r_n =0$ , then we have to prove a similiar equation will also hold w.r.t to any other origin provided $a_1 +a_2 + \cdots +a_n=0$

I thought about it , but could not get any start .

can anybody provide me a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you shift origin to $ b$, then the position vector of $P_i$ will be $r_i-b=r'_i $(let). Now rewrite the given condition.

$$a_1 r'_1 + a_2 r'_2 +\dots+a_n r'_n =a_1 (r_1-b) + a_2 (r_2-b)+\dots +a_n (r_n-b) =\sum a_ir_i-\sum a_ib$$

Now, $$\sum a_ir_i =0 ~\text{(given)}~;~\sum a_i=0 ~\text{(given)}~$$

Therefore $$a_1 (r_1-b) + a_2 (r_2-b) +\dots +a_n (r_n-b) =\underbrace{\sum a_ir_i}_{=0} -b\underbrace{\sum a_i}_{=0} =0$$